# What ω-language does a Büchi Automaton recognize?

Tags: computer-science, automata

When I'm reading about Büchi Automatons, it says that x is accepted if there are infinitely many occurrences of states from the set of accepting states in the run.

But for instance, when I'm being asked this:

[image]

I would say that both answer A, C and D is the correct answer, even though there is only one correct answer.

My thoughts:

A: When "1" is appearing in all even positions, the run will keep going through the accepting state.

C: If "1" is appearing in infinitely many positions, the run will also keep going through the accepting state.

D: If for all occurrences of the letter "1", there is a subsequent occurence of the letter "2", then the run will keep going from the first state to the accepting state and so forth = the run will also keep going through the accepting state.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is C. Regardless of what state it is currently in, the automaton moves to the initial state on reading a $0$ or $2$ and to the acceptor state on reading a $1$. Thus, it is in the acceptor state infinitely many times while reading the word if and only if the word has infinitely many $1$s.

The sets described in A and D are *proper* subsets of the language accepted by the automaton: every word in each of those sets belongs to the language, but so do other words that are not in those sets.

**Added:** As **mercio** notes in the comments below, that isn’t quite right: the set described in D actually *isn’t* quite a subset of the language, since it vacuously include all $\omega$-words that contain no $1$ at all.

Comment: I might have misunderstood something. For instance, regarding answer D,  would that language contain ω-words like "12" which wouldn't be recognized by the automaton?

Edit: I was just thinking, wouldn't the automaton read "12" as "1" and "2" etc. which would make it correct?

Comment: @Jacob: $12$ isn’t an $\omega$-word, so it’s irrelevant. The $\omega$-words over the alphabet $\{0,1,2\}$ are the *infinite* ternary sequences.

Comment: But what is then exactly wrong with lets say an infinite sequence "121212... etc."? Wouldn't the automaton read it as "1", "2", "1", "2" etc. which would make it keep going from the initial state to the accepting state?

Comment: @Jacob: Yes, it will oscillate between the two states. It will therefore be in the acceptor state infinitely many times, and the word will therefore be accepted.

Comment: What is then exactly wrong with answer D?

Comment: @Jacob: It describes only part of the language accepted by the automaton. For instance, the $\omega$-word consisting entirely of $1$s is accepted but is not described by D.

Comment: also, the word "0000..." is described by D but is surely not accepted by the automaton

Comment: @mercio: Thanks for catching that oversight on my part.

Comment: Thank you guys. I think I do understand it much better now :)

Comment: @Jacob: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Let $L$ be the recognized language of the Büchi automaton and $L_X$ the language described in part $X$.

$L_C$ is contained in $L$. Every word in $L$ has to be accepted along a path which contains the finial state infinite many times. The final state can only be assumed by recognizing a $1$ symbol. So $L$ is contained in $L_C$ too and $L = L_C$ follows.

$L_A \subsetneq L_C$ (e.g. $111011^\omega \in L_C$) and $L_B \subsetneq L_C$ ($(10)^\omega \in L_C$).

$D$ is wrong, $L_D$ would not contain $w = 11^\omega$, which is recognized.

That leaves $C$ as answer.